# Javascript edit iframe when content of textarea

Tags: javascript, html, editor, live

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change() {
document.getElementById('target').getElementsByTagName('html').getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML = document.getElementById('src').value;
}
</script>

<textarea id="src" onchange="change();"></textarea><br/>
<iframe id="target"></iframe>
```

This is my code and I don't understand why it isn't working. No jQuery please. I know things like this exist for example [htmledit squarefree](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/) I have tried frame instead of iframe and that hasn't worked either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aNQ24/2/) what you are looking for?  First I am using `onkeyup` on the textarea,  I don't think that textarea has an `onchange` event.  Then I am grabbing the iframe using two different methods depending on the browser and then populating the iframe with the text from the textarea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change() {
  var iFrame =  document.getElementById('target');
   var iFrameBody;
   if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) 
   { // FF
     iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   }
   else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) 
   { // IE
     iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   }
    iFrameBody.innerHTML = document.getElementById('src').value;
}
</script>

<textarea id="src" onkeyup="change();"></textarea><br/>
<iframe id="target"></iframe>​
```

Comment: one thing
    getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
if there is only one can't it just return that? I understand it works and why it does though, thank you for the simple snippet.

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a node list, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) for the docs.  however, you could just use `document.body`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
// Tested on Chrome 24 onchange is if you use backspace etc. use keyup for text
// It replaces \n with <br/> if you don't want that wrap the content in a <pre> tag
    document.getElementById("src").onchange=document.getElementById("src").onkeyup=function(){
        document.getElementById('target').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = this.value.replace('\n','<br/>');
    }
</script>
```